# Valgrind not showing source code for the dynamic library

Tags: valgrind

I'm trying to debug my program using Valgrind. I compiled with `-g3 -O0 -ggdb`. How ever I am unable to see the source code corresponding to the point where Valgrind finds problem. The output just shows the name of the (binary)library.

[image: Valkyrie screenshot]

Comment: May it be that you're using libtool?

Comment: @deeJ Can you please paste the output of valgrind.

Comment: @jcm I'm not using libtool. But thanks for pointing it out; it looks interesting.

Comment: @vishram0709 This *is* output for Valgrind. Do you want to see the entire .xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These addresses are of no interest. They belong to the runtime support code that runs after `main` and calls destructors of global objects and `atexit` routines. They do not have any source (that you wrote) associated with them.

You can tell that from their placement between `exit` and `__cxa_finalize` in the call stack. No user code could possibly belong there.

Comment: Indeed, you are right! Does that mean it is safe to ignore this error or that the error is being reported at wrong place?

Comment: Don't ignore, find out where these blocks are allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but do you have the source for that library?  If not, and that library wasn't compiled with debugging symbols, valgrind isn't going to decompile the binary and show you source.

Comment: Yes, I have source for 'libslm.so' and it was compiled with debugging symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is complaining about a double free on exit. The line:

```
Address 0x5980ec0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 29 free'd
```

Is pointing you where this memory block was previously freed. Taking into account that this is also in `exit` I can think of two possible reasons:

- Some global and static variables that are been freed (with C++ I've seen this problem when directly assigning two global objects, containing pointers, using default copy constructor. As both pointers refer to same memory address, on exit, this is freed twice).
- libslm.so has been loaded by using `dlopen`, then, on exit, it is closed and can also cause some problems with currently managed memory.

I'm assuming that `libslm.so` is yours so, I think, in both scenarios is important to know something about lines you marked. Have you checked that the path in the log is the same were you have your libraries with debug information? Is AddrScram linked against these libraries (with same exact path)?

Comment: @deeJ Did this help? Have you checked your linking paths?

Comment: I did check the linking paths and their were correct. However, I was able to solve the error using another approach. I will write a detailed answer soon.